# How to check if a discord message exist?

Tags: discord.js

I ask the user to give the message id to react and my bot crash even in a try catch if the message id is wrong. I'd like to return 'This message doesn't exist'.

Here the part of code

```js
const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id;
message.reply("veuillez indiquer l'id du message");
    message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
      max: 1, 
      time: 600000,
      errors: ['time']
      }).then(async(collected) => { 
        msgid = collected.first().content;
        try{
          channelid.messages.fetch(msgid);
          isMsg = true;
        }catch{
          message.reply("Ce message n'existe pas");
        }
      }).catch(() => {
       message.reply("Vous avez mis trop de temps a répondre");
      })
```

And I get this error

```
D:\Storage\Bureau\Projets\Dev\Bots\Discord\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:154
      throw new DiscordAPIError(request.path, data, request.method, res.status);
            ^

DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message
    at RequestHandler.execute (D:\Storage\Bureau\Projets\Dev\Bots\Discord\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:154:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:93:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (D:\Storage\Bureau\Projets\Dev\Bots\Discord\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:39:14)
    at async MessageManager._fetchId (D:\Storage\Bureau\Projets\Dev\Bots\Discord\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\MessageManager.js:135:18) {
  method: 'get',
  path: '/channels/785415753595486208/messages/8288745866573906',
  code: 10008,
  httpStatus: 404
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, `collected.first()` already return a [Message](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message).

If you want to fetch a message, you first need a valid id. So you need to use `channelid.messages.fetch(collected.first().id);` instead.

Then, you can use a `catch()` method to check if the message doesn't exist.

```js
message.channel.messages.fetch(collected.first().id).then(message => console.log(message.content))
  .catch(error => message.channel.send("I can't find a message with this ID"));
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working with


```channelid.messages.fetch(collected.first().content).then(message => console.log(message.content)).catch(error => message.channel.send("I can't find a message with this ID"));```